# iOS7 xCode 5, how to get crash logs from a development build on device?

Tags: ipad, logging, ios7, xcode5, crash-reports

I playtested the game that I'm making on my development iPad, while it was not connected to xCode. There were 4 instances where the game just crashed/closed.

If I remember correctly, these crashes should create a crash report which can be visible in the Organizer>Devices>Device Logs. However, upon checking this, I see only 1 (instead of 4) reports, most of which are marked as "unknown".

**Is there a way for me to refresh the device logs, or make sure that my device does keep logs** of all crashes that happened while not connected to xCode?

[image]